# Как сделать вращение 3D объекта с помощью клавиатуры?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

Здравствуйте. Есть следующий код, который вращает 3D объект по оси X при перемещении мыши.

```
    private void scrollViewer_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement z_uie = sender as UIElement;
        System.Windows.Point z_point = e.GetPosition(z_uie);
        sliderX.Value = sliderX.Maximum - (z_point.X / scrollViewer.ViewportWidth * sliderX.Maximum);
    }
```

Как сделать вращение при нажатии клавиши влево или вправо на клавиатуре? Т.е. при нажатии влево должен происходить поворот влево на 360 градусов, а при нажатии вправо должен происходить поворот вправо на 360 градусов.

Comment: Поворот вокруг оси на 360 градусов == отсутствие поворота.

Comment: Ну или на 180 хотя бы на любой угол. Главное чтоб был поворот. Сейчас он происходит с помощью мыши а нужно сделать тоже самое только с помощью клавиатуры.

Answer (score 2):

Если приложение не имеет фокуса ввода, то потребуется [установка хуков](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/ralph/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8), из которых нужно будет вызывать функции, вращающие объект. Это можно сделать самостоятельно, но проще подключить [библиотеку по работе с хуками](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/).

Кроме того, можно периодически опрашивать клавиатуру на предмет нажатия интересующих клавиш:

```
public delegate void Checker();

private void Listen()
{
    control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Checker(CheckForKey)
    );
}

public void CheckForKey()
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
        // ...
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
        // ...

    // TODO: перезапустить через некоторое время
}

public const int VK_LEFT = 0x25;
public const int VK_RIGHT = 0x27;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
internal static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vkey);
```

Comment: А как подключить эту бибилиотеку к проекту я вроде подключил т.е. кинул в проект и написал using MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor но при нажатии клавиш ничего не проиходит.